# Split csv file into smaller csv files every 30 days using awk

Tags: csv, ubuntu, unix, awk

I have a csv table that has a column that contains the date difference in days as integer values, and I want to split the file into 30 day intervals, such that the first file contains rows with the column values 0-30, the second one containing 31-60, and so on. How can I do that using the awk or split command?

Sample data:

```
ID, creation date, answer date, difference in days
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 0
```

Whenever the last column `(difference in days)` reaches 30 then I want to split the file with all the previous rows moved to the new file.

I tried this awk command but the results are not what I wanted:

```
awk -F, '{if($14 % 30 == 0) x="F"++i;}{print > $14/30"months.csv"}' file.csv
```

Comment: How can we help you when you do not share any sample data (as TEXT, not as PICTURE), and do not show what you already tried ?

Comment: @Luuk updated, sorry.

Comment: When you use `$14` it will reference the 14thc column (based on the separator ",".  Because you only have 4 columns the value of `$14` will be empty.

Comment: The original table has 14 columns but it's cropped for privacy concerns. The column mentioned is the 14th column so the awk command references the wanted value correctly.

Comment: on stackoverflow, you are _required_ to post a [mre]. When you post sample data, you should make sure that the sample data matches the code you are posting.

Comment: is the data already sorted by the last column? what is the expected max number of 30-day periods in a given file? 5? 10? 100? 1000's?

Comment: `$14/30"months.csv"` is going to create a subdirectory named `(value of) $14` and a file named `30months.csv`; please confirm this is what you want; better yet, provide a larger sample (eg, 5-10 rows) with data that would go into 3-5 expected output files, then show the names and contents of the expected output files

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest using integer division here rather than increase-when-divides-evenly, consider following sequence

```
1 2 3 4 7 9 10 10
```

and say you are dividing into size-5 interval, now if you increase-when-divides-evenly that would give

```
1 2 3 4 7 9 - 10 - 10
```

so two group were joined into one because no `5` is present and another was split into 2 groups due to repeated 10. Using integer division would give

```
1 2 3 4 - 7 9 - 10 10
```

Simple GNU `AWK` implementation let `file.txt` be

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
7,7
9,9
10,A
10,A
```

then

```
awk '{print > "file" int($1/5) ".txt"}' file.txt
```

creates `file0.txt` holding

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

and `file1.txt` holding

```
7,7
9,9
```

and `file2.txt` holding

```
10,A
10,A
```

Explanation: `int(x/y)` is integer division it does divide then takes floor.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{ i=0; x="F"++i }{print > "months_"x".csv"}{if($4 % 30 == 0 && $4>0) x="F"++i;}' input.csv
```

- `BEGIN{ i=0; x="F"++i }` initialize `i` and `x`
- `{print > "months_"x".csv"}` copy line to "months_{x}.csv",
- `{if($4 % 30 == 0 && $4>0) x="F"++i;}`  Only after copying the line, check if the column (the 4th one) has reached 30, and change `x`.

NOTE: The header will only be in the first output file ("months_F1.csv")

With this input:

```
ID, creation date, answer date, difference in days
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30
```

the following files will be created:
"months_F1.csv"

```
ID, creation date, answer date, difference in days
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30
```

and "months_F2.csv"

```
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not using the "x" variable you defined. Assuming it's not necessary you can simply change to, also assuming the field of interest is the last field

```
$ awk -F, '!$NF{$NF=1} {if(print > ( int(($NF-1)/30+1)"_months.csv" )}' file.csv
```

first 30 days will be in file `1_months.csv`, 31-60 in file `2_months.csv` etc.  If there are too many months you may need to revise to script to close the previous months. If the file is date sorted it will be simpler.

First part is to assign 1 to day 0, since it the first section has a span of 31 days (0-30) compared to other sections which are 30 (31-60).

Answer (score 0):

The sample data file.csv

```
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 1
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 2
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 32
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 33
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 34
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 65
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 65
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 66
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 67
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 91
```

split.awk

```
BEGIN {X=1; Y=30}
{  
  if($4 > Y) { X++; Y=X*30; }; 
  if ($4 <= Y){ print $0 >X"-file.csv"}
}
```

run this:

```
gawk -F, -f split.awk file.csv
```

result:

```
cat 1-file.csv
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 0
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 1
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 2
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 30

cat 2-file.csv
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 32
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 33
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 34

cat 3-file.csv
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 65
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 65
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 66
1190, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 15:14:00.53 UTC, 67

cat 4-file.csv
610, 2017-10-24 13:57:15.91 UTC, 2017-10-24 14:58:17.77 UTC, 91
```